# How can I test inner text of a div element

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, queryselector

I'm trying to find the best practice to test textContent for a div element here, using react testing library.

Say I'd like to test this simple react component to see if `{props.text}` is rendered properly on the HTML DOM.

```
const Simple = props => (
  <>
    <div> {props.text} </div>
    <div> test text </div>
  </>
);
```

I've tried to use `getByText`, then test `expect(getByText('text passed as prop')).toBeDefined()` but it didn't seem to work properly.

It must be much easier if I add a className or id for the first `<div />` then probably I can just go for `querySelector`, but what if I didn't want to add any HTML attribute here? How can I locate this element properly?

Is there any solution to find the first  element that has no attribute and test its inner text?

Comment: You have a space either side of your text in the `<div>`. Have you included that in your expectation?

Answer (score 4):

It works for me using `"@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0"`. E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Simple = (props) => (
  <>
    <div> {props.text} </div>
    <div> test text </div>
  </>
);

export { Simple };
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Simple } from './';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('60534908', () => {
  it('should find div element', () => {
    const mProps = { text: 'text passed as prop' };
    const { getByText } = render(<Simple {...mProps} />);
    expect(getByText('text passed as prop')).toBeDefined();
    expect(getByText('test text')).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60534908/index.test.tsx (8.606s)
  60534908
    ✓ should find div element (37ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.784s, estimated 11s
```